# What is the cheapest, most efficient printer that's compatible with Linux?

Tags: 10.04, printing, compatibility, elementary, kodak

Being that my Kodak printer (I will no longer get any more kodak printers) doesn't work properly any more (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/165586/how-do-i-get-my-kodak-esp-c310-printer-to-print-pictures#comment203103_165586) and tomorrow being tax free weekend starting up, I wanted to see what people (you) thought would be the best printer to get that's compatible with Linux.

One that's ink lasts a long time and when it does run out, it doesn't cost a handful for a refill. (Why I bought my kodak printer to begin with)  I'm currently using Ubuntu 10.04, and whenever the new Elementary comes out, I'll be using that.

So, either way, as long as it runs on Linux and is cheap and efficient, I'll be a happy camper.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: This kind of question is more suited to a forum than this site. As it stands this is too subjective and open-ended for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather open ended question so it is likely to be closed(by the mods, not by me), but to answer your question in a general sense before they do....

HP printers have a good reputation for working with linux.
I am currently using an HP2050 all-in-one and it work flawlessly with 12.04 worked with 11.10 and 11.04.

As far as the ink, that is rather subjective and depends on how much printing you do, I don't do a whole lot.  I can only say that it is much better on ink than my Lexmark all-in-one(which didn't work with Linux at all). The ink is about;

Black: $18 for the regular $30 for the high yield(they call it XXL, if I remember right
Color: $25 and $35 I believe, I have not had to buy color ink yet but I did look at it when buying black.
These were the ink prices at my local Dept. store, not sure online but likely cheaper by 20% or more....

I did research to find compatible printers when I needed one and found that most people recommended HP as the most compatible.  I bought my HP for under $50 if I remember right.

I did a quick search on  www.ubuntuforums.org and found this question, it is about 12.04 but still HP is the most recommended

[Which (cheaper) printers work with ubuntu 12.4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032095&highlight=printer+compatible)

Finally, in the post I linked to this link was included, I did a quick check of it and it will allow you to search by Manufacturer and or model # and will tell you how well it works with linux..... http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Comment: Was about to mention HP2050 myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Canon Pixma printer. There are a few different models, but it is a reliable printer. We have had it for about 9 months and have not had one issue. It is a network printer so you can print wireless. Here is a link to Canon's [webpage](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/office_all_in_one_inkjet_printers) about it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you by experience that the printers that better work on Linux are HP and Epson. HP has more advanced experience in printers than Epson, but Epson printers are very reliable and usable. HP printers are a little more yielding but the cartridges are not so cheap. Epson cartridges are cheaper, but sometimes they don't have a good yielding. Also, if you buy an Epson printer your printer will have a lot of years of support (unlike HP). I have a cousin with the same Epson printer since 2006 and its fully supported and compatible with Windows, Mac and Linux latest versions.